# How to create a setup file that will install an executable Jar

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jar, installation

I've created a Java application in Eclipse JavaEE on Windows (yay for me!!) and I compiled it into an executable jar. I created a .bat file that runs that jar. I put that all into a folder system with the required images and libraries to run my program successfully.

Now I want to install this onto other computers.

I am OK with just clicking the bat file but I want my users to be able to see the program displayed in the startmenu, and launch it from there. I am thinking of creating a setup.exe to handle the installation, but not sure how (iexpress.exe works for .exe programs) I don't really need the setup.exe it would suffice to just add program to the start menu and point it the bat file, but how??

Comment: I can not compile it any other way. I am replicating an old software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) tool. A fairly powerful, scriptable, installer creation system with a very manageable learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of installer generators that either support Java applications, or are specifically designed to create installers for Java programs.  Of the latter category [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) is one of the better known.  I've never developed an installer with IzPack so I cannot offer you a developer perspective but I've encountered several software packages that use IzPack (see their [references](http://izpack.org/we-love-izpack/)), and the generated installers are very nice.